# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0

Tags: react-native

*I try to get apk in react-native however it doesnt give me anything. release file which is in apk file is empty and after `grandlew bundleRelease` is finished, it says :*

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

I couldnt find how to solve this issue

*My signingConfigs which is in app/build.grandle* :

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
```

*in gradle.properties:*

```
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE=my-upload-key.keystore
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD=password
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD=password
```

*After I create my-upload-key.keystore, I copy my-upload-key.keystore from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin and paste to android/app. is something wrong ?*

Answer (score 0):

By default, Gradle won’t display all warnings (e.g. deprecation warnings). Instead, Gradle will collect them and render a summary at the end of the build.
Try specifying warning mode via gradle.properties like so:

> org.gradle.warning.mode=all

And please let us know if it works.